# Any idea how I can refactor this any further

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, refactoring

I'm new to rails and i've really tried my best to keep refactoring this method but this is the smallest I can get it to. Any ideas as to what i can extract or refactor? etc

```
def create
 if verify_recaptcha
  super do |resource|
    if resource.save
      pin = resource.create_pin(otp: new_otp)
      begin
        SendMessage.new({pin: pin.otp, contact_number: resource.contact_number, first_name: resource.first_name}).send_otp
      rescue Exceptions::ServiceDownError
        sign_in(resource)
        return redirect_to users_otp_verification_path(user: @user.uuid, service_status: true)
      end
      sign_in(resource)
      return redirect_to users_otp_verification_path(user: @user.uuid)
    else
      return render :new, resource: resource
    end
  end
  else
     flash.now[:alert] = 'There was an error with the recaptcha verification. Please verify that you are human.'
     flash.delete :recaptcha_error
     return render :new, resource: build_resource(hash = nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: Post your question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you can do:

```
def create
  if verify_recaptcha
    super do |resource|
      return render :new, resource: resource unless resource.save
      begin
        SendMessage.new({pin: resource.create_pin(otp: new_otp).otp, contact_number: resource.contact_number, first_name: resource.first_name}).send_otp
      rescue Exceptions::ServiceDownError
        sign_in(resource)
        return redirect_to users_otp_verification_path(user: @user.uuid, service_status: true)
      end
      sign_in(resource)
      return redirect_to users_otp_verification_path(user: @user.uuid)
    end
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'There was an error with the recaptcha verification. Please verify that you are human.'
    flash.delete :recaptcha_error
    return render :new, resource: build_resource(hash = nil)
  end
end
```

I don't know what 'service_status: true' means inside a ServiceDownError... but I guess you can do:

```
def create
  if verify_recaptcha
    super do |resource|
      return render :new, resource: resource unless resource.save
      begin
        SendMessage.new({pin: resource.create_pin(otp: new_otp).otp, contact_number: resource.contact_number, first_name: resource.first_name}).send_otp
      ensure
        sign_in(resource)
        return redirect_to users_otp_verification_path(user: @user.uuid, service_status: true)
      end
    end
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'There was an error with the recaptcha verification. Please verify that you are human.'
    flash.delete :recaptcha_error
    return render :new, resource: build_resource(hash = nil)
  end
end
```

Or maybe:

```
def create
  if verify_recaptcha
    super do |resource|
      return render :new, resource: resource unless resource.save
      status = nil
      begin
        SendMessage.new({pin: resource.create_pin(otp: new_otp).otp, contact_number: resource.contact_number, first_name: resource.first_name}).send_otp
      rescue Exceptions::ServiceDownError
        status = true
      ensure
        sign_in(resource)
        return redirect_to users_otp_verification_path(user: @user.uuid, status: status)
      end
    end
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'There was an error with the recaptcha verification. Please verify that you are human.'
    flash.delete :recaptcha_error
    return render :new, resource: build_resource(hash = nil)
  end
end
```

To go further you could extract this in a separate method:

```
{pin: resource.create_pin(otp: new_otp).otp, contact_number: resource.contact_number, first_name: resource.first_name}
```

like:

```
private

def message_params(resource)
  {
    pin: resource.create_pin(otp: new_otp).otp,
    contact_number: resource.contact_number,
    first_name: resource.first_name
  }
end
```

Remember that refactoring is not just about making the code small, but also making it cleaner and easier to read, so extracting things to smaller methods can be a good idea

Comment: You're a genius bro, I thank you sincerely! You have really opened my eyes to the art of refactoring. I genuinely used to think refactoring was focussed mainly on making the code take up less lines of code irrespective of its readability. The way you have presented my code not only works but it is really readable! Thank you once again kind sir!

Comment: No problem, Ruby is a language that let's you write very nice and readable code so take advantage of that. It's good to read the code out loud and try to think if a person that doesn't know how to code or a person that is reading the code for the first time could understand "what" it does. The private methods should hide the "how". If the task is too complex then it will be hard or impossible to refactor without making it worse. Try Rubocop gem to help you out writing the code